# Git Bash Terminal Keeps Closing When Minimized

Tags: terminal, git-bash

I recently switched computers and after installing Git Bash on my new computer I'm having some issues. It has never happened to me before and I am not finding much information online about my issue. Every time I minimize the window the terminal closes. I'm trying to run a server for the backend of my application and it's really starting to frustrate me. Has anyone has this problem before? What can I do to stop my terminal from closing every time I minimize it?

Comment: Can you please add some additional information such as what OS you are using and what version? What version of git bash you are using?

Comment: You might check if the program is crashing and not really closing when you minify it. https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/windows-10-crash-log.html

Comment: Also, if you're using VS Code, do you have the same problems using its integrated terminal? It should be using your git bash terminal within the editor. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Note that git-bash is not Git itself: it's a port of the Linux version of bash (command line interpreter) to Windows. Git needs this kind of CLI, so Windows versions of Git often come with this git-bash port. Minimizing a window should not make the CLI in the window terminate, but I'm not a Windows user and have never seen this happen, much less a way to fix it if it does happen.